# Can't make my spring boot application work with jsp

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I have problem with my **spring boot** web app. It uses **embedded jetty** (it must be jetty - not tomcat) and it uses **jsp** views. But seems like there is no way to make embedded jetty work with jsp views. Actually at the moment when I run mu app server starts successfully but when I try to access any url of my web app - I get error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:591) ~[apache-jsp-8.0.27.jar:2.3]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:397) ~[apache-jsp-8.0.27.jar:2.3]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396) ~[apache-jsp-8.0.27.jar:2.3]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340) ~[apache-jsp-8.0.27.jar:2.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
......................
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:231) ~[apache-jsp-8.0.27.jar:2.3]
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:577) ~[apache-jsp-8.0.27.jar:2.3]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363) ~[apache-jsp-8.0.27.jar:2.3]
```

How can I make it work? Is there any way?
And if it is not possible with spring boot then what are **alternative ways** to make my app work on embedded jetty with jsp?

Here is link to my project on [github](https://github.com/IngeniousTom/DVDExchange-on-spring-boot-). Please look at it and help me! It would be just great if you try to run it in your IDE (IntelliJ IDEA recommended) and find the reason of the problem.

**UPDATE 1 (15.07.2016)**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [sample.jetty.jsp.SampleJettyJspApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:187) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
    at sample.jetty.jsp.SampleJettyJspApplication.main(SampleJettyJspApplication.java:33) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163) ~[spring-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Spring Boot 1.3.6 and in the [JSP limitations section of the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) it says:

> Jetty does not currently work as an embedded container with JSPs.

There's [an enhancement](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/5290) coming in Spring Boot 1.4 that means the JSPs will work with embedded Jetty as long as you use war packaging. If you don't want to wait for 1.4.0 to be released, the enhancement is in 1.4.0.RC1 which is available from https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone. There's also a [new sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.4.0.RC1/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp) that may be of interest.

Comment: Thank you so much but when I run the sample you gave me I get error - look at update!

Comment: There's a bug in IDEA. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237768/run-spring-boots-main-using-ide) for more details

Comment: in the question there is no any certain answer. One person asked to give example of workaround but nobody gave it! I understood that there are 3 ways to workaround this 11 years old IntelliJ IDEA problem: 1-using fake module with all lib (no example of how to do), 2 - something with Xclasspath (no example too), 3 - custom maven profiles (no idea what is that). Could you helpe me please? with example please?

Comment: Lots of examples here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107048